# Enable OAuth 2.0 implicit flow capability for the Azure AD application

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, implicit-flow

I am trying to run the application for my study on using microsoft graph rest api in outlook web add-in. I found this [link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/master/Samples/Outlook.ConsumeGraphAPI).They have asked to Enable OAuth 2.0 implicit flow capability for the Azure AD application in the setup instructions. I would appreciate if you can help me with this. Additional links related to using microsoft graph API would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: That is an old and outdated sample (note that it has been archived by the owner). I would suggest starting with [Use the Outlook REST APIs from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api).

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I was using the Outlook Rest API but there is a limitation where i could not send mail using Rest API in the desktop version of Outlook. So now i am trying to use the Microsoft graph API to overcome the limitation

Comment: Outlook REST API and the Outlook endpoints in Microsoft Graph have the same capabilities. (Graph is relaying calls to the Outlook REST API behind the scenes). The key difference is that Office.js doesn't provide an SSO token for Graph, only for Outlook REST API. If you use Graph you'll need to authenticate the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of just enabling implicit flow on an Azure AD / Microsoft Graph application, you can do it in the [App Registration portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com).

After you login, look inside `Platforms` > `Web`, and check the `Allow Implicit Flow` button.  If you don't see the `Web` platform, you can click `Add platform` and configure the app.